# LDAP query get all groups (nested) of a group

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, active-directory-group

I want to list all groups in a Active Directory, including nested.

With this I get the top level groups:

```
try {
    Hashtable<String,String> props = new Hashtable<String,String>();
    props.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://adserver");
    props.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "user@domain");
    props.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");

    DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(props);

    SearchControls cons = new SearchControls();
    cons.setReturningAttributes(new String[] {"cn"});
    cons.setSearchScope(SearchControls.ONELEVEL_SCOPE);

    NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> answer = ctx.search("cn=users,dc=domain,dc=com", "(objectcategory=group)", cons);
    System.out.println("AD GROUPS:");
    while(answer.hasMore()) {
        SearchResult result = (SearchResult) answer.next();
        Attributes atts = result.getAttributes();
        Attribute att = atts.get("cn");
        String groupName = (String)att.get();

        //how to search for groups nested in this group
    }
} catch (NamingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

How can I fetch nested groups? I googled a little and found this two ways:

```
NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> nested = ctx.search("cn=users,dc=domain,dc=com", "(&(objectClass=group)(objectCategory=group)(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.194:=cn="+groupName+"))", controls);
```

and

```
NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> nested = ctx.search("cn=users,dc=domain,dc=com", "(&(objectClass=group)(objectCategory=group)(memberOf=CN="+groupName+"))", controls);
```

But this is not returning the nested groups. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Important for Active Directory to have memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941 if you want to find nested groups (do not replace this magic numeric string).

```
(&(objectCategory=Person)(sAMAccountName=*)(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=Test group,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=net))
```

Comment: What is the magic string? Will it always work irrespective of past or future AD versions?

Comment: You know, it's Microsoft. It's always unpredictable in the future. Till now it works. According to https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx  " It is available only on domain controllers with Windows Server 2003 SP2 or Windows Server 2008 (or above)."

Comment: The 'magic' is an OID:  1.2.840.113556 means Microsoft.  They're free to change below that root, but 1.4 from there is Active Directory so they're locked-in there.  1941 is called "LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN" so it's really well-constrained.  Them having actually registered everything openly isn't a guarantee of stability, but it's a small comfort that it'll cost too much in churn for something arbitrary now.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do next

```
Attribute memberOf = srLdapUser.getAttributes().get("memberOf");
if (memberOf != null) {
  for (int i = 0; i < memberOf.size(); i++) {
      Attributes atts = ctx.getAttributes(memberOf.get(i).toString(), new String[] { "CN" });
      Attribute att = atts.get("CN");
      groups.add((att.get().toString())); 
  }
  System.out.println(groups.toString());`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use filters for category as follows

(&(objectCategory=user)(memberOf=cn=MyCustomGroup,ou=ouOfGroup,dc=subdomain,dc=domain,dc=com))

Comment: What about the nested groups?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
(&(objectClass=group)(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=" + groupDn + "))
```

Comment: What is the magic string? Will it always work irrespective of past or future AD versions?

Answer (score 0):

In LDAP we can query if a User belongs to a given group once you have established a connection you can query using either member or memberOf attribute.

Query for memberOf Attribute :
filter used : (&(Group Member Attribute=Group DN)(objectClass=Group Object class)) Ex : (&(memberOf=CN=group,ou=qa_ou,dc=ppma,dc=org)(objectClass=group))

Using member Attribute :
filter used : (&(Group Member Attribute=User DN)(objectClass=Group Object class)) Ex : (&(member=CN=user,ou=qa_ou,dc=ppma,dc=org)(objectClass=group))

But You'll have to search recursively using the member or memberOf attribute list for a user. e.g. if a user has the following group hierarchy :

cn: user1 memberOf: CN=group1,DC=foo,DC=example,DC=com memberOf: CN=group2,DC=foo,DC=example,DC=com

then you'll want to recursively lookup group1 and group2 with additional LDAP searches, and so on for groups which those groups are members of.

We can't use LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN in production since it doesn't work when we have too deep nested hierarchy and it only works for Active Directory. Below Solution works independently with AD or OpenLDAP we just need to replace the group attributes.

Below is the sample code to query all the nested groups a User belongs to :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.NamingEnumeration;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchControls;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchResult;

public class MemberDemo {
    private static final String contextFactory = "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory";
    private static final String connectionURL = "ldap://10.224.243.133:389";
    private static final String connectionName = "CN=administrator,CN=users,DC=ppma,DC=org";
    private static final String connectionPassword = "Conleyqa12345";

    public static int nestLevel = 3;
    public static int level = 1;

    // Optional
    private static final String authentication = null;
    private static final String protocol = null;
    private static String userBase = "OU=qa_OU,DC=ppma,DC=org";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();

        // Configure our directory context environment.

        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, contextFactory);
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, connectionURL);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, connectionName);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, connectionPassword);
        if (authentication != null)
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, authentication);
        if (protocol != null)
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, protocol);

        InitialDirContext context = new InitialDirContext(env);

        SearchControls constraints = new SearchControls();
        constraints.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);

        Set<String> traversedGroups = new HashSet<String>();
        Set<String> relatedGroups = new HashSet<String>();
        List<String> tempParentColl = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<String>();
        List<String> tempGroups = new ArrayList<String>();

        String loginUser = "CN=qa20Nest,OU=qa_OU,DC=ppma,DC=org";

        String filter = "(&(member=" + loginUser + ")(objectClass=group))";
        tempGroups = findNestedGroups(tempGroups, context, filter, loginUser, constraints,
                tempParentColl, traversedGroups, getUserName(loginUser));
        relatedGroups.addAll(tempGroups);

        System.out.println("Parent Groups :");

        for (String group : relatedGroups) {
            System.out.println(group);
        }
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long elapsedTime = end - start;
        System.out.println("Total time taken in sec : " + elapsedTime / 1000);

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public static List<String> findNestedGroups(List<String> tempGrpRelations, InitialDirContext context, String filter,
            String groupName, SearchControls constraints, List<String> tempParentColl, Set<String> traversedGrp,
            String groupIdentifier) {
        NamingEnumeration results;
        try {
            traversedGrp.add(groupName);
            results = context.search(userBase, filter, constraints);

            // Fail if no entries found
            if (results == null || !results.hasMore()) {
                System.out.println("No result found for :" + groupName);
                if (tempParentColl.isEmpty()) {
                    return tempGrpRelations;
                } else {
                    tempParentColl.remove(groupName);
                }
            }

            while (results.hasMore()) {
                SearchResult result = (SearchResult) results.next();
                System.out.println("DN - " + result.getNameInNamespace());
                tempParentColl.add(result.getNameInNamespace());
                tempGrpRelations.add(result.getNameInNamespace());
            }

            Iterator<String> itr = tempParentColl.iterator();
            while (itr.hasNext()) {
                String groupDn = itr.next();
                String nfilter = "(&(member=" + groupDn + ")(objectClass=group))";
                tempParentColl.remove(groupDn);
                if (!traversedGrp.contains(groupDn)) {
                    findNestedGroups(tempGrpRelations, context, nfilter, groupDn, constraints, tempParentColl,
                            traversedGrp, getUserName(groupDn));
                }
            }

        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return tempGrpRelations;
    }

    public static String getUserName(String cnName) {

        String name = cnName.substring(cnName.indexOf("CN=")).split(",")[0].split("=")[1];
        return name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try changing

```
cons.setSearchScope(SearchControls.ONELEVEL_SCOPE);
```

to

```
cons.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
```

This should allow you to search the entire subtree below and including  the level you have specified